# VBA Loop to do a stock portfolio calculation but save output in separate column on another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, while-loop

I am doing a stock portfolio performance sheet and need the value of the portfolio at each date. I have two sheets, a transaction sheet and a calculation sheet. I am trying to do up a code whereby the calculation moves on a loop based on each transaction date but I want the output of the calculation in a separate column on the transaction sheet. As you can see I am a newbie and here is the code I have done but it keeps getting an error after about the second date. I have tested the loop of the calculation without trying to put the value in the transaction sheet and that works. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub Calc_nav()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim mnt As Range

Dim i As Integer

i = Worksheets("NAV Cal").Range("F2")

Set mnt = Worksheets("Transactions").Range("K7")

Do While i <= Worksheets("NAV Cal").Range("F3")

Worksheets("NAV Cal").Range("C2").Value = i

mnt.Value = Worksheets("NAV Cal").Range("C4")

Set mnt = mnt.Offset(1, 0)

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Sheets("Transactions").Select

Application.ScreenUpdating = False



i = i + 1

Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Comment out the `Application.ScreenUpdating=False` and `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` until at least after you have got all the code working - they will just hide errors and make it more difficult to fix anything.

Comment: Sorted it. I added the following line Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:4")) ahead of mnt.Value = Worksheets("NAV Cal").Range("C4") and that sorted it . Thanks